# How to upload photo from given folder path

Tags: php

I am using PHP 5 and I want to add a link **Upload photo from album**,
when I click to this link a photo browsing window will open & it will only contain the specified photo album folder's photos. Just like in facebook link to Upload photo from your photo album..

Thanks.

Comment: Your question seems pretty vague to me, what exactly do you want ? What you ask for seems pretty programmable so at what point you ran into trouble ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the question here is, because writing that would take up some serious time, even for advanced developers. You may probably want to get into reading about http://jquery.com and especially http://jqueryui.com/ for the Browser Window.

With this, you can create a `div` in PHP that reads the user's photo library and writes it into it. Then, with jQuery, you can dynamically open and close the `div` as a popup.

jQuery implements some neat functions with whom you can check what photo the user clicks in the popup and then send that back to a php-file that uploads the photo wherever you want.

Still, with that vew information, you should really consider trying some solutions out yourself and if you encounter problems that are more specific to a special functionality, you can ask SO again.